# Dynamic webpage using django and python

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am unable to connect my javascript file in with my html page in my django app.
I have created a separate folder and placed the **script.js**. 
Inside html file;

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="JS files/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) to manage the the static files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in a static folder and call it as

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'JS files/script.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: yes, inside static folder create JS files folder and put there

Comment: It's throwing another error;`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'`